# ERROR in Unexpected value 'null' declared by the module 'AppModule in /home/conor/Desktop/repos/minviro-db-tool-frontend/src/app/app.module.ts'

Tags: angular, typescript

Upgrading versions of angular and I have updated my app.module.ts updating the HttpModule to the HttpClientModule and now I am getting the error ERROR in Unexpected value 'null' declared by the module 'AppModule in /home/conor/Desktop/repos/minviro-db-tool-frontend/src/app/app.module.ts'

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import DatabaseComponent from './database/database.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import DbSearcherComponent from './db-searcher/db-searcher.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DatabaseComponent,
    DbSearcherComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    routing,
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you try to include `CommonModule`?

Comment: Yeah added there and no change.